# Open URLs in Chrome Notifications

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

Sorry if my Question is vague but this is what I am basically trying to do.
My chrome extension app basically looks at a forum and whenever a new thread is posted, a desktop notification shows up. It uses Chrome notifications API.So it looks something like this:

> chrome.notifications.create("id0", options,callback)

options is the template so I can make something like:

```
var options = {
  type: "basic",
  title: "NEW THREAD!",
  message: "I made a new thread blah blah blah",
  iconUrl: "url_to_small_icon"
}
```

So when a user clicks the notification, it should open a link of that thread.

***Question is how should I do this?***

At first, I figured I should just add the url under options template (something like options.message = "www.google.com") and then once ***chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener*** is called, I would grab that link from options, but I don't think that would work as I cannot grab any info on the notification itself other than the notificationID (in this case, it would be 'id0'). (If I'm wrong, please tell me a way to do this. Thanks!)

A way I thought of is to have an array of the URL of the new threads that my chrome extension app found (Let's say 3 new threads has been posted) and then once ***chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener*** is called, I would check the notification id (in this case id0), and then find the value of the array using the index (in this case, 0) and then open that URL. This does work, but I need to delete that element at some point as my array will increase as we see more new threads.

The problem is, if I delete that element right after I clicked the Notification, I shift the array (The array had a size of 3, but now it'll have 2) and when a user clicks another notification, (let's say notification 'id1'), that will open an element that does not have the proper URL (it should open array(0), not array(1) because I deleted the first element).

Note That the user can click id0, id1 or id2 at any order so I cannot delete the element in the notification if the notifications are displayed.

One thing I could try to do is delete the array once all the notification has been clicked, however I dislike this method....

I'm sure there is a better way so I was hoping you guys can help me out?

Chrome Notifications example: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/richNotifications
chrome.notifications api: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications

Comment: use an object keyed by id instead of an array.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the forum URL as the notificationId and you won't have to use an array at all.

For example:

```
var forumUrl = 'https://example.com/thread/42';
var options = {
  type: "basic",
  title: "NEW THREAD!",
  message: "I made a new thread blah blah blah",
  iconUrl: "url_to_small_icon"
}

// create notification using forumUrl as id
chrome.notifications.create(forumUrl, options, function(notificationId){ }); 

// create a on Click listener for notifications
chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function(notificationId) {
  chrome.tabs.create({url: notificationId});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Now you can attach the extra payload in `options.data = {}` as key value pairs.

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  console.log(event);
});
```

Comment: Source for this? Minimum Chrome version? It's not reflected in the docs.

Comment: as far as i know its working for 44+, and for 50+ you can also attach 2 cta buttons with actions, which you can access in event listener

Comment: Wait, still, suppose you attach `.data`. In the listener you still ONLY get the notification ID.

Comment: In a event listener on notification click, you get the full notification object and action with event.

Comment: Well brother I am using it for 50+ and its working great. Simply add any key value pairs in payload.data.
self.registration.showNotification(payload.title,payload);
and the event listener will give you the same payload in event.Notification

Comment: I fail to see how your sample code relates to `chrome.notifications` API that this question is about.

Comment: this sample code is supposed to be use in service-worker.js, are you using a HTML5 notifcation which simply relies on the script and works only if the tab is open?

Comment: This question _is not about [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification)_, it's about [`chrome.notifications` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications). That's the source of confusion.

Comment: Ya i am talking about Chrome only, but recent update of chrome-50 came with major changes in chrome notifications, i guess you should have a look at it.

Comment: Again, to hammer home: HTML5 Notification API, and `notificationclick` event, are **not** part of the `chrome.notifications` API, and if you read this question, it is specifically about `chrome.notifications`. As such, your answer is not on topic.